# Display description in Dbeaver instead of value

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

Hi im running a SELECT statement where im trying to display a database, and from there i need to export this table to a csv. My problem is that i don't want to display the value rather the description which is the real value, see photo below.

[image]

I have tried to find a setting for this but have failed. I don't know where to look or begin.

Answer (score 0):

You must join second table to your first table. For example:

```
Select ft.page_id, ft.objective_id, st.description as activity_title 
from first_table ft
inner join second_table st on ft.activity_title_id = st.id;
```

Comment: Thank you i could see the table needed in "define description"